# Java JUnit JVM_EnqueueOperation() stubbed

Tags: jvm, ibm-jdk, visual-c++-runtime

I get this error while trying to run a JUnit Test on eclipse Oxygen Using Ibm's jdk8.

Is there any known bug in this version of jdk? How can I fix/avoid it?

---

[image: Assertion failed!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the unit test uses PowerMock, which does not currently support IBM JDK.

PowerMock tries to load an agent via HotSpot Attach Mechanism, but it should use J9 attach mechanism instead.

See the following issues for details:

- https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/3441
- https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/970

Comment: No we don't use PowerMock. But we use JMockit, Mockrunner and EasyMock.

Comment: @BakriBitar Anyway, this or the other mocking library relies on the bytecode instrumentation. You need to include the agent JAR at JVM startup with `-agentpath` option. Otherwise the library tries to load the agent JAR at runtime using HotSpot Dynamic Attach Mechanism and fails, since J9 attach mechanism works differently.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by adding the Mocking-Library path as VM Argument to the JRE as already stated by apangin.

To do that:

`Window`→ `Preferences` → `Java` → `Installed JREs`: select JDK, edit it and add the following to `Default VM Arguments`:

```
-javaagent:<YOUR_M2_REPO_PATH>/org/jmockit/jmockit/1.9/jmockit-1.9.jar
```

[image]